# Finding volume of region rotated around y-axis.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

I see now that (obviously) the volume can't be negative, but if I use the absolute value of it, is it the correct volume?

Here's my math on how I got the volume:
$$V=\int2\pi x(6sin(2x^2))dx$$

Use u-sub:
$$u=2x^2\;\; {du\over4}=xdx$$
So,
$$V=12\pi (-cos(2x^2)*{1\over4}) \;\; Where\;\; a=6 \;\; and\;\; b=2$$

After using a and b, I get the current volume in the bow with the red "X" by it.

Thanks for any help! These are just non-graded homework problems, but I think I'll learn more if someone points out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

EDIT: nvm, I found out the answer is $6\pi$. I'm still not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: You did not do anything wrong until the last step. Why sub in 6 and 2? You should sub in $x = 0$ and $x = \sqrt{\pi/2}$

Comment: Shoot. That may be where I went wrong. I thought the upper limit was always b and the lower is a. It may be that those are the names of the constants in the function. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

$$
\begin{align}
V&
=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi/b}}x~y~dx\\
&=2\pi a\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi/b}}x~\sin(bx^2)~dx\\
&=\frac{\pi a}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\sin t~dt,\quad t=bx^2\\
&=-\frac{\pi a}{b}\cos t\biggr|_0^{\pi}\\
&=\frac{\pi a}{b}
\end{align}
$$

In the present case we get $V=3\pi$. I have verified this results numerically.